# define basic matrix type (typedef 2d array)

Tags: c

why doesn't the following line of code work?

`typedef float[MAT_ROW_SIZE][MAT_COL_SIZE] mat;`

what should I do?

(I wanna avoid defining a struct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identifier (the name) must come first. Try

```
typedef float mat[MAT_ROW_SIZE][MAT_COL_SIZE];
```